# How do I solve an intermittent media-disconnected error that only happens on my home network?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

When I connect to my router wirelessly, it won't give me Internet access. My housemates have no such issue, and the network is fine for me over Ethernet. *Very* occasionally the Wi-Fi will work again until I restart or sleep my laptop.

I'd suspect my network card, but thing is, I can connect to every other Wi-Fi network.

I've tried resetting the IP stack, 'forgetting' the connection, resetting the router to factory, and pacing widdershins round the derelict carcass of a UNIVAC I while chanting the name of Jupiter's innermost moon. No dice. If I type `netsh` one more time I might implode.

(I realise a question like this has been asked, and solved, a few times on a few forums. None of the solutions I found has worked for me. I'm sure I'm being a fool, but I'd greatly appreciate it if somebody could point out exactly how I'm being a fool.)

Comment: Not all Wi-Fi networks are equal. Maybe yours uses a different channel or other parameters incompatible with your card?

Comment: I had a similar issue some days ago with a cheap notebook. The solution was to reset the network settings, it's a "hidden" option inside Win10: Settings -> Network -> Status -> Network Reset (at the bottom).

Comment: It could be a result of how your specific Wi-Fi card interacts with that router. I had an issue like that with a public Wi-Fi hotspot on an old laptop; the laptop worked perfectly at home, at work, and at all other hotspots, but I couldn't get it to connect the hotspot served by this one chain.  I'd suggest playing around with the network adapter settings.

Comment: @grawity: I forgot to mention that this started happening only recently. It worked flawlessly before.

Comment: @freginold: Sigh, back to the network adapter settings. (Thanks for the precise edit, by the way.)

Comment: @brainwash: No luck, alas. I think your solution is another route to the netsh IP stack–reset command I referred to earlier. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @crisis.sheep With mine, I never figured out the issue because I didn't get to that hotspot often, but it happened after I disabled the WiFi one day while connected. Every other connection worked fine except at those hotspots. I suspected a setting somewhere got reset but didn't have many chances to find it.

Comment: You say it won't give you Internet access; will it let you connect to the local network wirelessly?

Comment: Yes, connecting wirelessly to the local network works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This could very well be an issue with your wifi adapter interoperating with your wifi access point.  Here are a couple of things to try:

1. Try upgrading your wifi adapter driver.
2. Try upgrading your wifi access point firmware.
3. Buy a new wifi USB adapter.
4. Change your wifi access point channel to a "less" congested channel (Rare on 2.4GHz these days to find a less congested channel, but try anyway).
5. Make sure you are not at the edge of the wifi coverage boundary.
6. Cordless Phones and Microwaves will affect your 2.4GHz connection stability - make sure those are not in use when you are experiencing wifi issues.  Then you can rule those out.

Comment: @crisis.sheep #3 is a really good idea. Get a cheap USB/Wi-Fi adapter and try to connect off that instead of your internal network card. That should help isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, everybody! I'll give them a bash as soon as I can!

Comment: Hiya @pythonian. I've tried all your suggestions, and it's still iffy. (Interestingly enough, the USB adapter worked for about ten minutes, then cut out.)

Comment: @crisis.sheep - Could there be some kind of virus on your computer altering your wifi connectivity? Or maybe some kind of wifi denial of service in your area.  I'm out of ideas - Sorry.